# Edit Image like adding text and brush after capturing image from camera or gallery in android?

Tags: android

Following code is for adding filters, light adjustment and cropping images

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.EXTRA_ASSIST_CONTEXT);
editIntent.setDataAndType(photoURI, "image/*");
editIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(editIntent, null));
```

Is there any similar way from which I can add text or apply brushes on the captured image?

Comment: You can draw over a bitmap using a canvas. That's what I used to make a little "fingerpaint" for an app I'm working on. It works pretty simply, you create a canvas by giving it the bitmap you want to work on. And then you apply modification to the canvas to finally retreive the modified bitmap. I'll try to answer with a little code sample as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to add path and text over your bitmap, as I don't know what you mean by brush I can't help you with that.

```
mPaint = /* a paint with all the caracteristic like color, thinkness, etc that you want to apply to your text*/
mBitmap = /* in memory bitmap */
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
mCanvas.drawText("your text", xStartingPosition, yStartingPosition, mPaint);

/*The bitmap is modified directly so you can access it normally*/
doStuffWithPaintedBitmap(mBitmap);
```

I hope this will help you